# bluetoothctl scan: Can´t find some devices; Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
HW: AMD PC A10- 2012; Bluetooth USB Dongle supports BT 5.0
I have a Bluetooth controllable socket which does communicate with my tablet (Samsung)
Im trying now to connect this to my Unbuntu-PC starting with scanning for the MAC Address.

`$ blutoothctl`
`#scan on`

This won´t find the device. Also my tablet cannot be found.
Only a Samsung TV speaker-set  from the floor below sometims shows up.

So scan seems to run,but why do I miss some devices in the scan?

Comment: Append the output of `lsusb` terminal command while the dongle is connected

Comment: Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio<b>
Bus 008 Dev 3 should be the devce<b>